# mouseover on Combo box in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, combobox, mouseover

I have static combo box in html with some default value already selected and other values we can select from drop down. I want to call javascript function onMouseOver. But it is not working. Can we associate events with combo box ?

Comment: show us some code or make an example on jsfiddle.net with what you have tried.

Comment: @MoinZaman Sorry for not posting the code. I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>foo</option>
<select>
```

And JS:

```
document.getElementById('sel').onmouseover = function() {
    alert('bar')
}
```

Works fine. You can see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/TSzUK/

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes it is working. But can't we have it as attribute like we have with other tags. For e.g. <p onMouseOver = "fun1()">Some Paragraph</p>

Comment: Your code works too, at least in Firefox 13. Just two notes: I would user event name lowercased and it's not nice to write events inline.